# When testing a mixed http/https site how to browse back to http after browsing to https?

Tags: http, firefox, https

I'm testing a mixed http / https site, where most pages are served as http, but one is served as https, and ran into this:

Say you browse `http://foo` and that works fine.  Then you browse `https://foo`, and that works fine.

But then want to browse `http://foo` again, (same page, but not SSL), well FireFox and Chrome continue to serve you `https://foo` and IE will serve you `http://foo`.

Clearing browsing history will fix Chrome but how do you you tell FireFox to forget?  Clearing browsing history won't do it.

[Edit: The reason the browser remembers that https has been seen and so later does not allow http requests is to implement [Strict-Transport-Security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security).]

Answer (score 0):

In FireFox: History | Clear recent history | Site Preferences